# Typeorm return contents of fields based on type

Tags: typescript, express, typeorm

I have the following TypeORM entity

```
@Entity()
export class SuperResource extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(() => Resource, {cascade: true, eager: true})
  @JoinColumn()
  resource: Resource

  @Column({type: "enum", enum: ResourceTypes})
  type: string

  @Column()
  created_at: Date

  @Column()
  modified_at: Date
}
```

I also have several entities that `extends` the `Resource` entity, for example:

ETLs

```
@Entity()
export class Job extends Resource {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  jobId: number;

  @Column()
  description: string;
}
```

Tables

```
@Entity()
export class Table extends Resource {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column()
  database: string

  @Column({ type: 'enum', enum: Datasources, default: Datasources.Other})
  datasource: Datasources;
}
```

Being `Resource` the following entity

```
@Entity()
export abstract class Resource extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string

  @Column()
  regulatory: boolean
}
```

Now, when I execute a query, for example, `repository.findOne({ where: {id: parseInt(id)}})`

The object returned on the field `resource` is of type `Resource`, meaning I´m not getting the full information inside the object.

¿Is it there a way to return the information inside the `resource` field based on the Type of the object?

It can be solved by doing 2 queries, but I´m not sure if there´s any other way.

Thanks!

Comment: please provide revelant code about `repository.findOne()`, especially where you defined `repository`.

Comment: Hi! repository.findOne() is an in-built method of the typeorm library being used.
https://typeorm.io/repository-api

Comment: i know `.findOne()` is buildt-in, what i need is how you called it, because normally it should return every column.

Answer (score 0):

The TypeOrm [documentation](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/entity-inheritance) contains examples of entity inheritance. You can solve your problem by using the `@TableInheritance` and `@ChildEntity` decorators.